# Matrix Transpose Well-defined

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a matrix,then both $X=AA^T$ and $Y=A^T A$ are well-defined and symmetrical matrices.

How do I prove this?

Answer (score 2):

You have a theorem in your book that says $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$, right? If you do, you can say this:
$$
X^T = (AA^T)^T = (A^T)^TA^T = AA^T = X
$$
and likewise for $Y$.

As for well-defined... My best guess would be that transposes are well-defined and products are well-defined, so doing both of them one after another would produce something well-defined.

Comment: The phrase "well defined" here refers to the fact that $A$ and $A^T$ have conforming dimensions so that they can be multiplied together. In general, given an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ and a $p\times q$ matrix $B$, they cannot form a matrix product $AB$ unless $n=p$.